# How to return a new queue object after every add() operation?

Tags: java, data-structures, constructor, queue

I'm writing a program to perform basic queue operations in Java. By far everything works well if the add() and remove() operations are performed on the same queue and then shifting the elements. I'm trying to do a bit more but I'm unable to achieve it. The problem is, during an add() operation, the program mustn't add elements to the existing queue, instead it must return a new Queue object with the added elements. New queue objects must be created as many times the add() operation is executed, any help regarding how this can be done?

Comment: FYI this is called a purely functional or persistent data structure.

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: @JBNizet I've tried the basic operations - add(), remove(), peek() using front & end pointers, that is done. I am unable to figure out how can I make the program to return a new queue object.

Comment: Your question implies that every add creates a new queue with a single element in it. Is that really what you mean? Or have you misses cribbed the problem,or misunderstood it? It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @EJP No, it returns a new queue with the 'addition' of the new element. eg: queue1 = {1,2,3} ; add(4); queue2 = {1,2,3,4}

Answer (score 1):

You can use the copy constructor of your collection class to make a clone of the queue, add the new item, then return the clone. For example, LinkedList has the [copy constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#LinkedList%28java.util.Collection%29).

```
public Queue<T> myAdd(Queue<T> oldQueue, T newElem)
{
  Queue<T> newQueue = new LinkedList<T>(oldQueue);
  newQueue.add(newElem);
  return newQueue;
}
```